# Running Selenium for an external website from Django

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-models, automated-tests

I have a standalone Python-Selenium bot which simulates user interaction in an external website. I would like to write some of the details which get from the website into a database. So I like to integrate the existing bot into Django framework to make writing into the database easier.

I wonder whether it is possible to integrate this standalone project into Django. If yes, I would like to know how can I trigger the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger your bot any way you like, e.g. via cron job. However, there are a couple things to consider. First, your bot needs to run from the same virtual environment as your Django project. Second, your Django project root must be available in `sys.path`. Something like this:

```
import os
import sys
import django

sys.path.append('/path/to/your/django-project-root')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_project.settings')
django.setup()
# Do your stuff, e.g:
from my_app.models import MyModel

value1, value2 = get_data_from_somewhere()
MyModel.objects.create(param1=value1, param2=value2)
```

After running `django.setup()` you can execute any code in the context of your Django project, including saving your data via models API as shown in the example above.